# How to get the mean, skewness of an Itō integral?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, moments

If $B_t$ denotes a standard Brownian motion, and let $X_t = \int f(s)dB_s$, $f(s)$ is a deterministic integrand. I know $B_t$ is a martingale. Is $X_t$ also a martingale? And how can I get the formula of moment statistics of $X$, say, $E(X_t^2)$, $E(X_t^3)$?

Comment: For 1. and 2. moments the results are standard. You find something about these integrals (with necessary assumptions) f.i. in Karatzas/Shreve: Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus (1988),ch. 3, in particular p. 137 ff by specialization. Concerning skewness I think this is $0$, but I don't have a reference. Higher moments may be more difficult.

Comment: This is not MO level. Hint: since $f$ is deterministic, the integral is a Gaussian random variable.

Answer (score 1):

For the martingale part, this follows by the Ito construction increments $B_{t_{i}}-B_{t_{i-1}}$. That implies that the sum of them is also a martingale  $I(f^{n}) = \int_{0}^{t} f^{n}_u dB_u$ where $f^{n}$ are simple processes.

Then finally we use that the $L_1$-limit of martingales is still martingale eg. see here [When is the limit of Martingales a Martingale?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83304/when-is-the-limit-of-martingales-a-martingale)

To get the formulas for the moments we use the Gaussianity. Since $f$ is deterministic, we get that $X_{t}$ is Gaussian
with variance  $\mathbb{E}\int_0^t f(s)^2 ds$. [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3221012/let-x-t-int-0t-sigma-tdb-t-what-is-the-law-of-x-t?noredirect=1&lq=1)

The integral of a progressively measurable process $f$ is a limit of the integrals $I(f^{n}) = \int_{0}^{t} f^{n}_u dB_u$ where $f^{n}$ are simple processes and these integrals are Gaussian by definition.

Then as mentioned there we just use

> Let $X_n$ be a sequence of normally distributed random variables with mean zero and variances $\sigma_n^2 \in [0,\infty)$.  Suppose $X_n \to X$ in distribution.  Then $\sigma_n^2$ converges to some $\sigma^2 \in [0,\infty)$, and $X$ is normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.

In fact, this process is just a time changed Brownian motion [see here](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/04/20/time-changed-brownian-motion/)